# Is there a way to have R code that correlates all numeric columns for each categorical variable of a column to generate correlation for each category

Tags: r, tidyverse, correlation

Is there a way to have R code using tidyverse that takes a dataframe with numeric columns "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", and a categorical column "primary_disease" and automatically generates correlation for "col1" against all other columns based on each categorical variable in "primary_disease"

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = rnorm(100),
  col2 = rnorm(100),
  col3 = rnorm(100),
  col4 = rnorm(100),
  primary_disease = sample(c("disease1", "disease2", "disease3"), 100, replace = TRUE)
)

df %>%
  group_by(primary_disease) %>%
  summarize(
    col2_cor = cor(col1, col2),
    col3_cor = cor(col1, col3),
    col4_cor = cor(col1, col4)
  )
```

I would like the output of the above code, but in such a way that I don't have to manually indicate every correlation for every column that should be produced as my actual dataframe has >20,000 columns

Answer (score 1):

We may use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(primary_disease) %>%
   summarise(across(col2:col4, ~ cor(col1, .x), .names = "{.col}_cor"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  primary_disease col2_cor col3_cor col4_cor
  <chr>              <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 disease1         -0.0460   -0.277  -0.318 
2 disease2         -0.310    -0.462  -0.0693
3 disease3          0.0564    0.331  -0.224
```

---

In the `devel` version of `dplyr`, we may use `.by` in `summarise`

```
 df %>% 
    summarise(across(col2:col4, ~ cor(col1, .x),
      .names = "{.col}_cor"), .by = "primary_disease")
```

-output

```
  primary_disease    col2_cor   col3_cor    col4_cor
1        disease1 -0.04601285 -0.2769518 -0.31818835
2        disease2 -0.31042139 -0.4624959 -0.06933399
3        disease3  0.05635708  0.3306853 -0.22396487
```